# Second derivative of likelihood function

Tags: probability, statistics, derivatives, log-likelihood

Let $f_{\delta}(y) = \frac{y}{\delta^2}*e^(\frac{-y^2}{2*\delta^2})$

with $y\geq 0$

I set up the Likelihood function as $$L(\delta) = (\frac{y}{\delta^2})^n *e^(\frac{-\sum y^2}{2*\delta^2})$$

and the log likelihood as $$l(\delta) = n*ln(\frac{y}{\delta^2})+\frac{\sum y^2}{2*\delta^2}$$

Taking first derivative $$l'(\delta) = -\frac{2*n}{\delta}-\frac{\sum y^2}{\delta^3}$$

Second derivative $$l''(\delta) = \frac{2*n}{\delta^3}+\frac{3*\sum y^2}{\delta^4}$$

But this second derivative seems incorrect, but where do I go wrong?

I want to calculate the Fisher Information with the second derivative and calculate a confidence interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt:

Let $f_{\delta}(y) = \frac{y}{\delta^2}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2\delta^2}}$ with $y\geq 0.$

Then $$L(\delta) =\Pi_{i=1}^n f_{\delta}(y_i) = \frac{r}{\delta^{2n}} e^{\frac{-\sum_i y_i^2}{2\delta^2}}$$ where $r$ denotes the product of $y_i.$

Log likelihood is as $$l(\delta) = -2n\log(\delta)-\frac{\sum y_i^2}{2\delta^2}+C$$

Taking first derivative $$l'(\delta) = -\frac{2n}{\delta}+\frac{\sum_i y_i^2}{\delta^3}$$

Second derivative $$l''(\delta) = \frac{2n}{\delta^2}-\frac{3\sum_i y_i^2}{\delta^4}.$$

So yes you missed out a minus sign but also I would suggest you write $(y_1,...,y_n)$ rather than $(y,y,..,y).$

Edit:

This is how I would do the expectation for this $l''(\delta)$:

We now treat only $y_i$ as random variables and so $E[l''(\delta)]=\frac{2n}{\delta^2}-\frac{3}{\delta^4}E[\sum_i Y_i^2].$

Then you use linearity and this will end up finding the expected value of $Y^2,$ you can do this with the standard integral. (Or perhaps thinking about $Var(Y)=E[Y^2]-(E[Y])^2)$ can help?)

Comment: Thank you for your calculations, very helpful. Yes the sign change did it in the end. How would you go about taking the expectation of $l''(\delta)$ here?

Comment: @Le_Poisson I have added further details, lemme know if you need any more clarifications

Comment: I calculated the critical point to be $\delta = sqrt(\bar{Y_n^2})/2)$, so for $\bar{Y_n^2}$ I enter $2*sqrt(\delta)$, but then still, I have a n in the equation, which by expectation can't be there. How shall I adapt to this term?

Comment: I am assuming you are referring MLE here but I dont think that is the correct MLE. On the other hand, if you were to calculate the expectation of $l''(\delta)$ you dont need to substitute the MLE in, just treat $\delta$ as a constant, the expectation is over $Y_i's$

Answer (score 1):

You forget a - from the first to the second line.

Comment: Yes, very correct!